# Python selenium: Firefox auto download everything

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to download a csv file from a website and no matter how many MIME's I try for both saving and opening, the dialog box still appears. Is there a way to cover all MIME's at once or anything that might pop up?

Right now I'm using:

```
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/html")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","text/html")
```

And other variations including a ton more MIME's. How can I auto download regardless of the MIME?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my question with this:

```
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/octet-stream")
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.openFile","application/octet-stream")
```

I had multiple preference statements, and I think that is what the problem was. Now I only have this one active and don't have any problems. Hope this can help someone else.

Comment: Not exactly "regardless of mime-type" solution, but thanks for sharing.

Comment: I know, but it is the best I could find. I'll leave it unanswered for a while in case someone has a better solution.